# Calling a country's currency name from a web service using XML

Tags: xml, wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services, c#-3.0

This is the web service I'm trying to use. I am using Visual Studio 2010.
http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx

This is the code I have. I have added the web service to my web site, and there are no errors showing up in my environment. When I run the program and click my button, however, nothing happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void btnCountry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CountryInfo.country country = new CountryInfo.country();
        String countryName = txtCountry.Text;
        String currencyName = country.GetCurrencyByCountry(countryName);

        XPathNavigator nav;
        XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();

        myDoc.LoadXml(currencyName);
        nav = myDoc.CreateNavigator();

        lblCurrency.Text = nav.SelectSingleNode("//Currency").Value;
        String countryCode = nav.SelectSingleNode("//CurrencyCode").Value;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above sample i get back a response without any problem. Just make sure that the country name you pass to the web service as parameter needs to be in the list of countries that is exposed by the web service. You have a method "GetCountries" exposed by the web service. If there is no data for a country then it comes as an empty dataset.

Just try to use the countryName value "United Kingdom" and i can see the response as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <Name>United Kingdom</Name>
        <CountryCode>uk</CountryCode>
        <Currency>Pound</Currency>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Name>United Kingdom</Name>
        <CountryCode>uk</CountryCode>
        <Currency>Pound</Currency>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```